# PHP - Use instanceof to document variable type for IDE autocompletion

Tags: php

I am often using a PHP comment to explain the object type of a variable (mainly for the purpose of afterwards being able to use autocompletion features of my IDE for class methods, members).

Comment would look like this:

```
/* @var \Drupal\node\Entity\Node $node */
```

Now the IDE knows class of $node and can give me the methods etc.

This is very convenient.

Now I discovered that I can have the same if I check for the class of the variable as follows:

```
if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\Entity\Node) {
```

A small advantage of this is, that it does not hinder if you want to comment out a larger code block as the first variant does.

Can using instanceof primarly for the purpose of "declaring" a variable type like this, be considered a best practice or at least not a bad practice?

Comment: Wherever `$node` comes from: why not use proper type hints, such that the method generating that variable also provides the type information?

Answer (score 1):

In normal times it 's all about proper type hinting in PHP. I would say, that writing an if condition for autocompletion reasons can not be concidered as a best practice.

It 's like Nico Haase said in the comments already. Use PHP strict type hints. Your IDE will recognize type hints.

A simple example. Caution! This is strictly PHP 8 using constructor properties.

```
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel;

class LivingPlace
{
    public function __construct
    (
        protected string $place = '',
        protected string $zipcode = ''
    ){}

    public function getPlace(): string
    {
        return $this->place;
    }

    public function getZipcode(): string
    {
        return $this->zipcode;
    }
}

class Person
{
    public function __construct
    (
        protected string $name = '',
        protected int $age = 0,
        protected ?LivingPlace $livingPlace = null
    ){}

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getAge(): int
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

    public function getLivingPlace(): ?LivingPlace
    {
        return $this->livingPlace;
    }
}
```

As you can see every class method has a return type. The class constructors also have type hints for the class properties. This is clean code and your IDE knows know, what to expect, when writing code like follows ...

```
$place = new LivingPlace('Wiesbaden', '65205');
$person = new Person('Marcel', 41, $place);

// output: string(9) "Wiesbaden"
var_dump($person->getLivingPlace()?->getPlace());
```

The IDE knows automatically that it can use the `getPlace()` method when calling the `getLivingPlace()` method on the `$person` object.

Conclusion: Use type hints wherever you can. Writing @var comments or unnecessary `instanceof` if conditions are superfluous when using type hints.